# Sybase FSQL text-type column size limit

Tags: sybase

I need to execute a `SELECT`... from Sybase's command line tool, `FSQL`, which includes a `text` column as well (which contains some XML data).

Problem is, the data is chopped at 4096 characters.

How can I raise this limit as my data is larger than that. `FSQL -h` gives me no help - google neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original solution: to use `isql -o` instead of `fsql` which does not seem to have this limitation.

Updated solution:

Unfortunately both `isql` and `fsql` are limited by the default `@@textsize` parameter set in Sybase (on our server it is set to 32768).

To override the default issue the following command

```
SET TEXTSIZE 100000
```

before the query.